# Difference betwen docker and a setup script

Tags: docker

The question is deliberately mischievous, the answer is not that obvious.

One of the advertised added value of Docker is to make it able to reproduce dev or prod environments. This is done by creating images with the same dependencies, environment variables... everything needed by the environment is captured in the Dockerfile and this is great.

Now what is the difference between this Docker approach and a setup script that pulls the dependencies and code and sets up the environment variables?

Comment: "The question is deliberately mischievous, the answer is not that obvious." Is this supposed to be a trick question to which you already know the answer?

Comment: No trick at all, I am not fully clear yet about docker and I am expecting real insight here ;)

Answer (score 3):

One obvious point : **Isolation**.

If you run a setup script, you will have an environment witch will have complete installation and variables. But if you work on it, you risk to break your own setup. You can use a VM with this installation script instead (then, you have lot of articles on the net to provide difference between Container and VM, their strong points, etc.)

Another good reason: **Replicable**.

Your setup script can be run on lot of environment (ex: Linux Debian or Linux Ubuntu). If you use a container, it will always be the same environment (best is to have it iso or quite iso with prod environment so you can easily deploy).

Other points: **Scaling**.

You can test using one environment how your setup will scale.

There are probably much more reason ;) (easier to use and share for exemple ;) )

Comment: Interesting indeed. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Docker containers act as a sandbox, this is a major difference.  Environment variables, installed application dependencies and other components are localized completely within the Docker container.  When the container is removed, the host is not bloated with installation bits left behind.

Comment: Ha! "sandbox", this is a very self-explanatory word! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are self contained, will all the dependencies inside the image. And the result is run in isolation from anything else on the host. And when done, you can remove the container and image to free up space, or you can even reset to a known good state.

A setup script modifies the host environment to match a target, but you don't start from a known clean state and expose yourself to the risk of externalities.

What this means is that two setup scripts can negatively impact each other since they operate on the same host. If you have two scripts each requiring different versions of python or nodejs or tomcat, they will corrupt each others environment. And you have to cover every possible externality rather than starting from a known clean base.